# Remove text if duplicate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which basically looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">

<img src="#" />

<a href="#" class="link"> SomeText </a>

<a href="#" class="provider"> SomeText </a>

<div class="description">Text Text Text</div>

</div>
```

As you can see the text within `.provider` is the same as in `.link`
My question is: How do I remove the whole div (.wrapper) if there is such a duplicate of text? Please note the text is not set, it could be anything, so therefore its a var:

```
var text = $('.provider').text();

$('.wrapper a:contains(text)').remove();
```

This is one of my many attempt with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should do the job:

```
$('div.wrapper').each(function() {
    if($('.link', this).text() == $('.provider', this).text())
        $(this).remove();
});​
```

(example: http://jsfiddle.net/8b655/)

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this answer:) (strange though I can seem to get it to work in my on click event..)

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = $('.provider').text();

$('.wrapper a:contains('+text+')').parent().remove();​​​​​​​
```

may be this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.wrapper').filter(function(){
    var a = $('a.link', this).text(), b = $('a.provider', this).text();
    return $.trim(a) === $.trim(b)
}).remove()
```